# Truffle How to interact with deployed contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to interact with a contract deployed by a factory.

These are the factory and child contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Factory {
    mapping(address => address) public children; 

    function createChild() external {    
        //create master wallet
        Child child = new Child(msg.sender);

        //map child to sender
        children[msg.sender] = address(child);
    }

    function getChild() external view returns (address) {
        return children[msg.sender];
    }        
}

contract Child {
    address public owner;
    
    constructor(address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }
    
    function getOwner() public view returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to interact with these using web3 like this:

```
const Factory = artifacts.require("Factory");
const Child = artifacts.require("Child");

// create factory instance
const factory = await Factory.deployed();

// create child in factory
await factory.createChild();

// get child address
const childAddress = await factory.getChild();

// create child instance
const child = await Child.at(childAddress);

console.log(await child.getOwner());
```

I get a revert error:
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

The solidity code works fine on remix, but errors when ran with web3, any advice?

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.3.6 (core: 5.3.6)
Solidity - 0.6.6 (solc-js)
Node v16.1.0
Web3.js v1.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I was able to fix the issue by unboxing a new truffle project on another folder and copying over `truffle-config.js` and the contracts. Though I'm unsure what actually caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error might have been caused by not having `ABI.json` files or having the wrong versions of them. The reason for this is that Truffle is using `ABI.json` files to know contract addresses etc. Try to delete your ABI files and interact with contracts; you will probably get the same error.